# How can I use Oracle's virtualbox listpartitions command on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, partitioning, permissions

I'm using Oracle's VirtualBox (4.2.6r82870) on Windows 7 and I'm trying to list the partitions on my uSD card which is inserted in the computer as drive "E". I pulled open the Window's Computer Management->Disk Management window and I can see E is mounted as "Disk 1"

So initially I tried this command:

`C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1`

but I got back an error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Cannot open the raw disk: VERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

I read this was because I couldn't use this feature unless I was running as admin, so I found the VBoxManage.exe program, right clicked on it and selected Properties->Compatibility and picked to "Run this program as an administrator".

Now when I issue the same command it sits there for awhile then spits back:

> VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extended info not available)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.

What is the proper way to get this program to run correctly?

Comment: Run `cmd` as administrator and then use VBoxManage. And as far as I remember, VirtualBox cannot operate on mounted drives.

Comment: @gronostaj - Yes, opening the command prompt as an admin fixed the other window opening issue, but that was really just a side effect. The overall problem of the command not working remains.

Comment: That error makes it sound like you've got a problem with the installation.  Try repairing or reinstalling.  Can you run the VirtualBox GUI ok?

Comment: @heavyd - Yeah, I've been using the GUI and a number of it's mapping fetchers with no issues for months now, I just decided that I wanted to use the command line tool to check the partitions and once I ran that as Admin I started seeing this error. The GUI still works.

Comment: Have you tried unmounting the card? I mean unassigning a drive letter.

Comment: @gronostaj - Just tried it, same error. I ran the command on `-rawdisk E:` which came back as `VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` meaning it was succesfully unmounted, then I ran the command with `-rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1` again and it was the COM server not running as above